# IBotDataBag how to get all keys

Tags: c#, botframework

working with Microsoft Bot Framework I'm setting states and data for conversation and user management.

I used

```
var state = message.GetBotPerUserInConversationData<ConversationState>("State");
if( state == null)
{                       
    message.SetBotPerUserInConversationData("State", new ConversationState());
}
```

and

```
var data = context.PerUserInConversationData;
ConversationState state;
var ret = data.TryGetValue("State", out state);
```

to get my state.
Said that I should know properties, states I created calling Count property I get more then key/value pairs I created.

How to get the full list? It seems there is no way and may be object already inside whose name is unknown has info I need making useless my custom states.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you call context.PerUserInConversationData, you get the object that implements IBotDataBag (typically an instance of JObjectBotData class), and there is no way to programmatically access fields inside it.

If you want to understand which fields are inserted into this DataBag originally, you can have a look at the [Bot Framework Source Code](http://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder), or build you own copy of the framework which allows you to access keys in the JObjectBotData.

If you want to track your the fields that you put inside the bag in your code, you can create a wrapper which tracks those fields explicitly and stores their list in the DataBag.